# button load from xib via loadNibNamed() never called

Tags: ios, swift, xib, ibaction, loadnibnamed

Another problem arrived me. I have a view covering my hole screen. In it a webView for showing a youTube video and a button for closing. The view is load via loadNibNamed() and no matter what I'm doing, my IBAction never called by pressing that button.
I tried to make an IBAction via storyboard, also via addTarget to a buttonoutlet. Both never called. My button is reachable when I click it, it show the default touchanimation. Also printing the button outlet in viewDidLoad() says `<UIButton: 0x17d25430; frame = (15 8; 39 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x17d25ae0>>` so it is not nil.

My Layout looks like the following.

- MainScreen: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIWebViewDelegate{}

  - In one of mainScreens tableView is a customCell named videoViewCell implemented with:

  let cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("VideoViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! VideoViewCell

videoViewCell: UITableViewCell , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {}  has:

```
weak var delegate: ActivityDetailVideoCellDelegate?

...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    delegate?.selectedCellAtIndex(indexPath.row)
}

...

protocol ActivityDetailVideoCellDelegate: class {
    func selectedCellAtIndex(index: Int)
}
```

My mainScreen class has:

```
extension MainScreen: ActivityDetailVideoCellDelegate {
func selectedCellAtIndex(index: Int) {

    let youtubeLink: String = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(selectedVideo)"
    let youtubePopup = YouTubePopUpController()

    youtubePopup.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    youtubePopup.view.alpha = 0
    youtubePopup.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)

    let code: String = "<iframe width=\(youtubePopup.webView.bounds.width) height=\(youtubePopup.webView.bounds.height) src=\(youtubeLink) frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe> <style>body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }</style>"

    youtubePopup.webView.loadHTMLString(code, baseURL: nil)

    self.view.addSubview(youtubePopup.view)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
        youtubePopup.view.alpha = 1
        youtubePopup.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
    })
}
```

}

YouTubePopUpController: UIViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var closeButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(closeButton)

    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.closeButtonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

@IBAction func closeButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("close clicked")

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0
    }) { (finished) -> Void in
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

my xib:
[image: xib]

Comment: Looking at your view hierarchy, it looks like your closebutton is a child view of your web view. Try pulling it out of the webview and to be either a subview of your view or backgroundview

Comment: Yeah, was also my first suspicion but its on the same level like the webView, a different order give the same result

Comment: `userInteractionEnabled` isn't `false` by any chance, is it?

Comment: just test it, setting it manual on true, but this changes nothing

Comment: Is `myCustomCell` a `UITableViewCell` or `UIViewController`?

Comment: Moment, I have to correct something. oO

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere in the extension

Comment: Should I post some more information? I still have that issue. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my Problem by writing the `@IBAction func closeButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {}` inside my MainScreenViewController an adding Target inside `func selectedCellAtIndex(index: Int) {}` to call my youtubePopUp inside closeButtonClicked I made it global:

```
@IBAction func closeButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("close clicked")

    youtubePopup!.webView.loadHTMLString("about:blank", baseURL: nil)
    youtubePopup!.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.youtubePopup!.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
        self.youtubePopup!.view.alpha = 0
    }) { (finished) -> Void in
        self.youtubePopup!.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```